# passing functions as arguments in C

Tags: c

I'm looking through one of my textbooks, and I see the following line of code for a C function:

```
node_t* func(node_t* n, int f(node_t *))
```

What exactly does this mean? There is a function as an argument in there. What is the point of that? Shouldn't you just be able to call any function in the file as long as it's been declared?
Also, in terms of assembly, is it the memory location of int f() that is being referenced?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
node_t* func(node_t* n, int f(node_t *))
```

Is a function, called func that takes two parameters: n, a pointer to a node_t, and f, a pointer to a function that takes a node_t pointer and returns an int.  The function func returns a pointer to a node_t.

Anyway, the most common use of this that comes to mind is for generic algorithms.

"Shouldn't you just be able to call any function in the file as long as it's been declared?"

As long as the function has been declared in the compilation unit, and the linker can find it at link time, that is true.  However, function pointers are used when you want to be able to decide at run time which function to use (or compile time if you just want a generic function).

As a tangible example, consider [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/qsort/):

```
void qsort ( void * base, size_t num, size_t size, int ( * comparator ) ( const void *, const void * ) );
```

Now consider this:

```
typedef struct Student { int id; char* name; }

Student students[10];

//populate students

int sortByName(void* a, void* b)
{
    Student* sa = a;
    Student* sb = b;
    return strcmp(a->name, b->name);
}

int sortById(void* a, void* b)
{
    Student* sa = a;
    Student* sb = b;
    return a->id - b->id;
}

//sort by name:
qsort(students, 10, sizeof(Student), sortByName);

//sort by id:
qsort(students, 10, sizeof(Student), sortById);
```

The important part is that the sorting code didn't have to be changed.  The sorting implementation is effectively generic.  It's one algorithm that operates on different data types, and in this case, this generic-ness is facilitated by a function pointer.

There's other uses of function pointers as well (quite a few of them), such as call backs, or branching based on a map that maps something to a function.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument is a function pointer to a function with signature `int(node_t *)`. This way you can pass a call-back to `func`, like this:

```
int foo(node_t * p) { /* ... */ }

node_t n;
func(&n, foo);   //  note: the second argument is the function pointer
```

---

Here's a very stupid example to use this to move around a fictitious array:

```
T * array_next(T * arr, int n) { return arr + n; }
T * array_prev(T * arr, int n) { return arr - n; }

T * move_in_array(T * arr, T * (*f)(T *, int))
{
    return f(arr, 1);
}
```

Now you can write code that moves around in an array in a run-time determined fashion using the callbacks:

```
T * p = move_in_array(some_array, flag ? array_next : array_prev);
```

The key design idea here is that we have a generic action function `move_in_array` whose specific implementation is passed as an argument in form of a function pointer.